# Is low bias in a sample a synonym for high variance?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, variance, sampling, bias

Is the following true?

> low bias = high variance
>      high bias = low variance

I understand high and low bias but then how is variance different? Or are the above synonyms?

Comment: Variance really has nothing to do with bias.

Comment: Is this a generic question about statistical sampling? If so please untag [tag:neural-networks]. If it's specifically about neural networks, please explain why and add more context.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No. You can have both high or both low at same time. Here is an illustrate example. [picture and article source](http://scott.fortmann-roe.com/docs/BiasVariance.html) I also recommend you to read the article where this picture comes from.

[image]

---

The reason you have such impression is that in "early age" of machine learning, there is a concept called bias variance trade-off (as @Kodiologist mentioned, this concept is still true and a fundamental concept of tuning models today.)

- When increase model complexity, variance is increased and bias is reduced
- when regularize the model, bias is increased and variance is reduced.

In Andrew Ng's recent Deep Learning Coursera lecture, he mentioned that in recent deep learning framework (with huge amount of data), people talk less about trade off. In stead, there are ways to only reduce variance and do not increase bias (For example, increase training data size), as vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, do you have the link to the article?

Comment: Andrew Ng's remarks were probably related to "big data" machine learning. Both theory and practice suggest that when the data size is small, the bias-variance tradeoff very much matters.

Comment: The tradeoff still comes up quite often in the present. For example, regularized regression gets its predictive advantage over OLS by trading off variance for bias in a way that increases accuracy on net. Also, it's easy to come up with an unbiased estimator that has too much variance to be useful, and a 0-variance estimator that has too much bias to be useful.

Comment: @Kodiologist thanks for the comment. I revised my answer, hopefully it is better.

Comment: Yah, I definitely like it better now!

Answer (score 2):

The difference between bias and and variance is the same as between [accuracy and precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision):

[image]

> - The accuracy of a measurement system is how close it gets to a quantity's actual (true) value. (≈ bias)
> - The precision of a measurement system is the degree to which repeated measurements give the same results. (≈ variance)